# Execute a query that could have some parameters empty

Tags: c#, sql, string

Let me explain my problem really fast. I'm using Dapper.

I have to do a select with a Where clause. The problem of that query is that some parameters could be empty since i'm doing a filter query. Let me explain a bit better.

In my application you can have different filters. You can choose a surname, a vehicle plate, and 2 addresses.

I want to create a query that select only the rows that contains all the information, but you aren't force to use all the 4 filters at the same time, so you could have just the surname or maybe just the vehicle plate.

So, for now, i'm using:

```
string surname = driverComboBox.SelectedItem.ToString();
string vehiclePlate = vehicleComboBox.SelectedItem.ToString();
string sql = "WHERE"; //Starting point
if (surname != "*" && surname != "") //if he selected a surname
    sql += string.Format(" d.surname LIKE '%{0}%' ", surname); //add to the "WHERE" the string " d.surname LIKE 'surname')
if (vehiclePlate != "*" && vehiclePlate != "") //if he selected a plate
    sql += string.Format(" AND v.plate LIKE '%{0}%' ", vehiclePlate); //add to the sql string " AND v.plate LIKE 'vehiclePlate')
if (sql == "WHERE") //if it was only WHERE, so he didn't select any filter, just pass an empty string
sql = "";
UpdateTableRows(_controllerJourney.GetByFilter(sql)); //this controller just pass a WHERE clause that will append to a SELECT and then show the result on a datagridview, this works fine, so i wont' copy the code.
```

The problem with the above code (that works for now) is that there is probably a better way to do it. For example, if i have only the vehicle plate the sql will be

```
SELECT * FROM random WHERE AND v.plate like ***vehiclePlate***
```

So it will throw an error. That being said, is there a way to create a dynamic query?

PS: The above query was just an example, it's not the real select.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is usually solved by adding a dummy condition at the beginning of the `WHERE` clause, that will always be true.

```
string sql = "WHERE 1=1";
```

Then the rest of your code can simply add more conditions as needed, using `AND`. If no other condition was added, you don't need to remove the `WHERE` clause since it is still valid.

Code:

```
string surname = driverComboBox.SelectedItem.ToString();
string vehiclePlate = vehicleComboBox.SelectedItem.ToString();
string sql = "WHERE 1=1"; //Starting point
if (surname != "*" && surname != "") //if he selected a surname
    sql += string.Format(" AND d.surname LIKE '%{0}%' ", surname);
if (vehiclePlate != "*" && vehiclePlate != "") //if he selected a plate
    sql += string.Format(" AND v.plate LIKE '%{0}%' ", vehiclePlate); 
UpdateTableRows(_controllerJourney.GetByFilter(sql));
```

Comment: Wow, that was so simple. Thanks for helping me out!